# Retrieve info specific to user from database

Tags: mysql, database, image, blob

I'm working on a site that allows users to login and view photos they've taken with a photographer.  I'm uploading photos to a database as BLOB and with specific username attachments.  So my tables are set up like this:

DB name is user_register
Table 1 name is users 
With columns username, password, email
Table 2 name is images
With columns username, id, name, image

I've established a one to many relationship between the tables with username being the FOREIGN KEY.  What I'm needing to do is call the images for specific users when they have logged in for viewing. The idea is to call the images and have thumbnails, then, upon clicking, view full size in a slideshow of sorts.  I have the upload ability working, I just can't seem to fiND anything online to help me figure out how to call the info specific to the username, as all images are stored in the same db and that duplicate value is the commonality between them.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Yeah. It might help you db engine to not treat it like a file server for blobs

Comment: Does that have negative effects?  I never thought it would...

Comment: Think about what a db engine's core competenices are: optimized plans for retrieving data via sets and indexes and optimizations for joins and other strategies. Along come blobs: like someone spraying a sticky, gluey substance in the midst of it all.

Comment: But if they are images saved as data, how would it mess things up?  Sorry, I'm kind of new to databasing.

Comment: I think I summed it up. Can't improve it anymore. You will have to experience it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to your question above, You need to display the image into your website.
As far as i know, all website need a path for images you want to display. You have to make that images from db from blob to images then save it into your project path as jpeg or png its up to you. then this is the time you will be able to view the images you want to show the page you want.

Hope it helps buddy...

Comment: I appreciate your response.  I have coding available that will retrieve the blob and convert the page to an image, I'm still toying around with it to see how I can get it to work.